# Convert heirachy to dict of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hierarchy

I want to convert a hierarchy to a dictionary of lists.
I am just sharing the sample hierarchy. We need to write the recursive function for this but I am not able to get the idea how to write it

```
Input:
[('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'D', 'E'),
 ('A', 'D', 'F'),
 ('A', 'D', 'G'),
 ('A', 'D', 'G', 'H'),
 ('A', 'F')
]
```

I want output like

```
{'_id': 'A',
 'children':[
    {'_id':'B'},
    {'_id', 'C'},
    {'_id', 'D', 
     'children':[
       {'_id':'E'}, 
       {'_id':'F'}, 
       {'_id':'G', 
        'children':[
          {'_id':'H'}
        ]
       }
      ]
    }
    {'_id':'F'}
 ]
}
```

Comment: `{'_id', 'F'}` is missing in first children array?

Comment: I do not follow what is going on with F, in the output you placed it under D only. Should it not be the child of A as well (last tuple)? Was it intentional or a mistake?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed it

Comment: Did you still facing problem?

Comment: No it is solved